# Solubility of water in toluene

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I'm interested in studying the solubility of water molecules in toluene.

I already know that some water can dissolve in toluene. I've also done some calculations at DFT level using the C-PCM solvation model, but unfortunately, the DFT theory does not correctly describe all water's properties.

Is there somebody that has studied this phenomenon? I was able to find only toluene-in-water system.

Comment: Mutual Solubility Measurements of Hydrocarbon–Water Systems Containing Benzene, Toluene, and 3-Methylpentane is available from ACS at  J. Chem. Eng. Data 2008, 53, 1, 165–174
Publication Date:November 21, 2007
https://doi.org/10.1021/je700449z  but apparently it will cost you.

Comment: @JamesGaidis - depends if their institution has access. I get the full article with no issues. I'm sure a librarian can get it for them if the library doesn't have it.